# Add feature searching data values with arrays (type char) in C

Tags: c

So I make C programs (making database with array), combined from all post in this forum, which has **Create, Display, Update, Delete & Search** function, but when ***update, delete, search*** the data, it can only be done via **int values** which in my variable is **absen** or in English is **ID number**

I want to add feature to this program which can also ***search*** the data by string value, which in my variable is **nama, alamat & nohp** or in English is **Name, Address & Phone number**, and that code located in ***void search()***

Any and all help is appreciated.
Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//FUNGSI MENDEKLARASIKAN STRUKTUR DATA
struct data
{
 int absen;
 char nama[30], alamat[30], nohp[30];

}dat;
//FUNGSI MEMASUKKAN DATA
void insert()
{
 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen("Record", "a");
 printf("Masukkan nomor absen yg di inginkan : ");
 scanf("%d", &dat.absen);
 printf("Masukkan Nama      : ");
 scanf("%s", &dat.nama);
 printf("Masukkan Alamat    : ");
 scanf("%s", &dat.alamat);
  printf("Masukkan No Hp     : ");
 scanf("%s", &dat.nohp);
 fwrite(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fp);
 fclose(fp);
}
//FUNGSI MENAMPILKAN DATA
void disp()
{
 FILE *fp1;
 fp1 = fopen("Record", "r");
 printf("\nNo Absen\tNama\tAlamat\tNo HP\n\n");
 while (fread(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fp1))
 printf("  %d\t\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", dat.absen, dat.nama, dat.alamat, dat.nohp);
 fclose(fp1);
}
//FUNGSI MENCARI DATA (BERDASARKAN ABSEN)
void search()
{
 FILE *fp2;
 int r, s, avl;
 printf("\nMasukkan nomor absen yg ingin dicari  :");
 scanf("%d", &r);
 avl = avlabsen(r);
 if (avl == 0)
  printf("No absen %d tidak ada dalam database\n",r);
 else
 {
  fp2 = fopen("Record", "r");
  while (fread(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fp2))
  {
   s = dat.absen;
   if (s == r)
   {
    printf("\nNo absen = %d", dat.absen);
    printf("\nNama    = %s", dat.nama);
    printf("\nAlamat  = %s", dat.alamat);
    printf("\nNo HP   = %s\n", dat.nohp);
    
   }
  }
  fclose(fp2);
 }
}
//FUNGSI MENGHAPUS DATA (BERDASARKAN ABSEN)


void deletefile()
{
 FILE *fpo;
 FILE *fpt;
 int r, s;
 printf("Masukkan nomor absen yg ingin dihapus :");
 scanf("%d", &r);
 if (avlabsen(r) == 0)
  printf("No absen %d tidak ada dalam database\n", r);
 else
 {
  fpo = fopen("Record", "r");
  fpt = fopen("TempFile", "w");
  while (fread(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fpo))
  {
   s = dat.absen;
   if (s != r)
    fwrite(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fpt);
  }
  fclose(fpo);
  fclose(fpt);
  fpo = fopen("Record", "w");
  fpt = fopen("TempFile", "r");
  while (fread(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fpt))
   fwrite(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fpo);

  printf("\n>>>DATA TERHAPUS<<<\n");
  fclose(fpo);
  fclose(fpt);
 }

}
//FUNGSI MENGUPDATE DATA (BERDASARKAN ABSEN)
void update()
{
 int avl;
 FILE *fpt;
 FILE *fpo;
 int s, r, ch;
 printf("Masukkan no absen yg ingin di update:");
 scanf("%d", &r);
 avl = avlabsen(r);
 if (avl == 0)
 {
  printf("No absen %d tidak ada dalam database", r);
 }
 else
 {
  fpo = fopen("Record", "r");
  fpt = fopen("TempFile", "w");
  while (fread(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fpo))
  {
   s = dat.absen;
   if (s != r)
    fwrite(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fpt);
   else
   {
    printf("\n\t1. Update Nama dari no absen %d", r);
    printf("\n\t2. Update Alamat dari no absen %d", r);
    printf("\n\t3. Update No Hp dari no absen %d", r);
    printf("\n\t4. Update Nama, Alamat dan no HP dari no absen %d", r);
    printf("\nEnter your choice:");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    switch (ch)
    {
    case 1:
     printf("Masukkan Nama:");
     scanf("%s", &dat.nama);
     break;
    case 2:
     printf("Masukkan Alamat : ");
     scanf("%s", &dat.alamat);
     break;
    case 3:
     printf("Masukkan No HP: ");
     scanf("%s", &dat.nohp);
     break;
    case 4:
     printf("Masukkan Name: ");
     scanf("%s", &dat.nama);
     printf("Masukkan Alamat: ");
     scanf("%s", &dat.alamat);
     printf("Masukkan No HP: ");
     scanf("%s", &dat.nohp);
     break;
    default:
     printf("Pilihan SALAH");
     break;
    }
    fwrite(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fpt);
   }
  }
  fclose(fpo);
  fclose(fpt);
  fpo = fopen("Record", "w");
  fpt = fopen("TempFile", "r");
  while (fread(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fpt))
  {
   fwrite(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fpo);
  }
  fclose(fpo);
  fclose(fpt);

  printf("\n>>>DATA TERUPDATE<<<\n");
 }
}

//FUNGSI MENGECEK DATA (BERDASARKAN ABSEN)//
int avlabsen(int abs)
{
 FILE *fp;
 int c = 0;
 fp = fopen("Record", "r");
 while (!feof(fp))
 {
  fread(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fp);

  if (abs == dat.absen)
  {
   fclose(fp);
   return 1;
  }
 }
 fclose(fp);
 return 0;
}
//FUNGSI MENGECEK DATA KOSONG ATAU TIDAK
int empty()
{
 int c = 0;
 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen("Record", "r");
 while (fread(&dat, sizeof(dat), 1, fp))
  c = 1;
 fclose(fp);
 return c;
}
// PROGRAM UTAMA
void main()
{
 int c, emp;
 do
 {
  printf("\n\t---Silahkan Pilih---------\n");
  printf("\n\t1. MASUKKAN\n\t2. TAMPILKAN\n\t3. CARI");
  printf("\n\t4. HAPUS\n\t5. UPDATE\n\t6. KELUAR PROGRAM");

  printf("\n\n------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("\nSilahkan Pilih: ");
  scanf("%d", &c);
  printf("\n");
  switch (c)
  {
  case 1:
   insert();
   break;
  case 2:
   emp = empty();
   if (emp == 0)
    printf("\nData KOSONG\n");
   else
    disp();
   break;
  case 3:
   search();
   break;
  case 4:
   deletefile();
   break;
  case 5:
   update();
   break;
  case 6:
   exit(1);
   break;
  default:
   printf("\nPilihanmu salah\nSilahkan dicoba lagi...\n");
   break;

  }
 } while (c != 6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should read the string that will be the pattern to search, so where you read the number

```
printf("Masukkan no absen yg ingin di update:");
scanf("%d", &r);
```

change it to read the string.

Then you should compare the pattern string with every string in the struct (nama, alamat, nohp), so where you do have

```
s = dat.absen;
if (s == r)
```

you should type:

`string str = dat.nama; //To look up for the name`

and then make the comparison using the function `strcmp()`

Comment: So, I can search all of those 3 strings (nama, alamat, nohp) depending on what is the input?

Comment: Yes, and you even can search the same input pattern on all 3 attributes at the same time by chaining ```strcmp()``` functions, e.g.: ```strcmp(pattern, dat.nama) || strcmp(pattern, dat. alamat)  || strcmp(pattern, dat. nohp)```